# validating a string as ISO 8601 week number in java?

Tags: java, date

I have a string, is there a simple way to validate whether the string represents ISO 8601 week number in java?

```
String s="2012-W43-5"
```

This one represents 5 th day in 43 rd week in 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't throw a `ParseException`.

```
String string = "2012-W43-5";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-'W'w-u");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date date = sdf.parse(string);
```

Note that the [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) makes it non-lenient which thus means that overflowed values won't roll over.

Comment: It is throwing "Illegal pattern character 'u'" exception.

Comment: It's introduced in Java 7 which is out for more than 1 year already.